# Como popular uma tabela postgres com JSON?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, json, postgresql

Gostaria de popular as minhas tabelas com Json. Mas não estou conseguindo.
Alguém possui alguma solução?

Segue JSON:
https://gist.github.com/letanure/3012978

Comment: A pergunta está com a tag do postgres e mysql, em qual banco de dados você está tentando inserir os dados?

Comment: Para mim pode servir qualquer um dos dois...
Pois posso usar o pentaho para transferir de uma tabela para outra

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que a tabela de destino dos dados seja algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_foobar
(
    id BIGINT primary key,
    name TEXT
);
```

Você pode usar a função [`json_populate_record()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) do `Postgres` para inserir os dados em sua tabela a partir de um dado em formato `JSON`, veja só:

```
INSERT INTO tb_foobar( id, name )
(SELECT * FROM json_populate_record( NULL::tb_foobar, '{"id": 100, "name": "JOAO"}'));

INSERT INTO tb_foobar( id, name )
(SELECT * FROM json_populate_record( NULL::tb_foobar, '{"id": 200, "name": "MARIA"}'));

INSERT INTO tb_foobar( id, name )
(SELECT * FROM json_populate_record( NULL::tb_foobar, '{"id": 300, "name": "JESUS"}'));

INSERT INTO tb_foobar( id, name )
(SELECT * FROM json_populate_record( NULL::tb_foobar, '{"id": 400, "name": "MADALENA"}'));
```

Consultando:

```
SELECT id, nome FROM tb_foobar;
```

Saída:

```
|  id |     name |
|-----|----------|
| 100 |     JOAO |
| 200 |    MARIA |
| 300 |    JESUS |
| 400 | MADALENA |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2a753/1

**EDIT:**

No seu caso, o arquivo `JSON` de entrada possui vários registros. Voce pode usar a função [`json_populate_recordset()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) combinado com `WITH` para resolver o seu problema.

Assumindo que você tenho uma tabela similar a isso:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_estados_cidades
(
    id BIGSERIAL primary key,
    sigla VARCHAR(2),
    nome TEXT
);
```

Você pode implementar algo como:

```
WITH arquivo_json( doc ) AS (
VALUES (
'[
    { "sigla": "AC", "nome": "Acre" },
    { "sigla": "AL", "nome": "Alagoas" },
    { "sigla": "AM", "nome": "Amazonas" },
    { "sigla": "AP", "nome": "Amapá" }
  ]'::json))


INSERT INTO  tb_estados_cidades ( sigla, nome )
  SELECT
    rec.sigla, rec.nome
  FROM
    arquivo_json AS arq
  CROSS JOIN 
     json_populate_recordset( NULL::tb_estados_cidades, doc ) AS rec;
```

Consulta:

```
SELECT id, sigla, nome FROM tb_estados_cidades;
```

Saída:

```
| id | sigla |     nome |
|----|-------|----------|
|  1 |    AC |     Acre |
|  2 |    AL |  Alagoas |
|  3 |    AM | Amazonas |
|  4 |    AP |    Amapá |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d04cf/2

Comment: Show! e para importar um arquivo JSON? Existe essa possibilidade?